# i3: .config file error with window variables

Tags: linux, archlinux, i3

I was editing my config files of polybar and i3, when the arch throw a error

I customize my ArchLinux with polybar and i3, and i cant undersnteand some errors throwed by system. Therefore, i put a screenshot and my .config bellow:

[image: Screenshot o my desktop]

```
#focus, floating, & sticky
for_window [title="(?i)(?:copying|deleting|moving)"] floating enable
for_window [window_role="(?i)(?:pop-up|setup)"]
for_window [class=""]
popup_during_fullscreen smart
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg workspace $WS1


ERROR: CONFIG: Expected one of these tokens: <string>
ERROR: CONFIG: (in file /home/amts/.config/i3/config)
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 286: for_window [title="(?i)(?:copying|deleting|moving)"] floating enable
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 287: for_window [window_role="(?i)(?:pop-up|setup)"]
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 288: for_window [class=""]
ERROR: CONFIG:           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 289: popup_during_fullscreen smart
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 290: 
ERROR: CONFIG: Expected one of these tokens: <word>
ERROR: CONFIG: (in file /home/amts/.config/i3/config)
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 287: for_window [title="(?i)(?:copying|deleting|moving)"] floating enable
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 288: for_window [window_role="(?i)(?:pop-up|setup)"]
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 289: for_window [class=""]
ERROR: CONFIG:                              ^^
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 290: popup_during_fullscreen smart
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 291: 
ERROR: FYI: You are using i3 version 4.16.1 (2019-01-27)
```

Comment: How about starting with only a single `for_window` command and seeing what that gives you. One error at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing this line:

```
for_window [class=""]
```

or add application which you want in the class attribute or put * between the "" for all applications.

Answer (score 0):

you could enable i3 debugging

***if using ~/.xsession***

```sh
exec i3 --shmlog-size=26214400
```

more options found here:
https://i3wm.org/docs/debugging.html

btw what is `(?:)` mean to do? i have never seen it

Comment: I want to know too